# If Statement not working - any ideas?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, event-handling

I have been having some problems getting my if statement to work. In the html I have a drop down menu with three options, and depending on the options selected by the user a different set of text will be generated after pressing a submit button.

This is what I have in my script head:

```
function hair() {
    if (document.getElementById("hair").value == "2") {
        document.getElementById("background").innerHTML = "Well done, it worked!";
    }
}
```

And this is in the HTML in which I want JavaScript to correspond to:

```
<div id ="hair">
  What colour hair would you like your doll to have?
  <select name = "hair" id ="hair">
    <option id="brown" value="0">Brown</option>
    <option id="blonde" value="1">Blonde</option>
    <option id="red" value="2">Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I am essentially trying to get the page to say "Well done, it worked!" when the user picks 'red' and presses the button. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? I'm pretty much a beginner so simple explanations would be much appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: When are you calling hair() function

Comment: Where is the call of hair() ?

Comment: You have two IDs with name `hair`.

Answer (score 3):

You have some problem inside the code:

- you don't call the function on change select
- you have duplicate div hair, id must be unique

Try this:

```
function hair() {
    if (document.getElementById("select-hair").value == "2") {
        document.getElementById("background").innerHTML = "Well done, it worked!";
    }
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div id ="hair">
  What colour hair would you like your doll to have?
  <select name = "hair" id ="select-hair" onchange="hair()">
    <option id="brown" value="0">Brown</option>
    <option id="blonde" value="1">Blonde</option>
    <option id="red" value="2">Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```